# How can I identify a GuildMember in my leveling system?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using a leveling system with MySQL and currently I am using the User ID for the identifier for each row. The downside to this is that levels carry on through different servers. So, I need a way to identify a GuildMember.

I tried using GuildMember#id but it ended up being the same as the user id (weird!)

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM leveling WHERE id = '${message.guild.member(message.author).id}'`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let id = message.guild.member(message.author).id;
            // leveling stuff
}
```

I expected message.guild.member(message.author).id to give me a unique identifier for a GuildMember, but it was the same as the User ID.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully you find this answer helpful.

In the API, there is no unique identifier for [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s. [`GuildMember.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=id) is expected to be the same as [`User.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id) (the former simply returns the latter).

As for adding guild separation, you can add a column in your database for the [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) ID. That way, you can change and select values only within a specific server.

Example query:

```js
con.query(`SELECT * FROM leveling WHERE id = '${message.author.id}' AND guild = '${message.guild.id}'`, (err, rows) => {...});
```

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I'll try what you said, it's a really simple solution :)